# Date expectation failing after upgrading gem that has gem date 3.3.3 as dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, rubygems

This expectation was passing before I upgraded a gem that has [Date gem](https://github.com/ruby/date) 3.3.3 as a dependency:

```rb
# order.purchased_at = Sun, 26 Jan 0020 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
# order.purchased_at.class == ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
expect(order.purchased_at).to eq 'Sun, 26 Jan 0020 00:00:00 UTC +00:00'.to_datetime
```

For some reason adding Date gem 3.3.3 makes the above expectation fail, any idea?

Comment: From what version did you update?

Comment: It's probably due to different calendars ([Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) vs [Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar)). Your purchase date is in [year 20 of the 1st century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AD_20). Using a more recent date like 2020 should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your test actually reflecting what you need to test in your application code? Ie. are you actually converting datetimes with `to_datetime` and needing them to be true with compared with `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` using `==`?

I ask because it's really not surprising to me that:

```
main> dt = 'Sun, 26 Jan 0020 00:00:00 UTC +00:00'.to_datetime
Fri, 26 Jan 0020 00:00:00 +0000
main> dt.in_time_zone('UTC') == dt
false
```

As you can see, a `DateTime` does not include the actual timezone, just the offset, so any equality with an object that contains a timezone is a stretch. [Which is one of the reasons `DateTime` was deprecated as of Ruby 3.0](https://ruby-doc.org/3.0.6/exts/date/DateTime.html)

As the docs say, use `Time` instead:

```
main> tt = Time.parse 'Sun, 26 Jan 0020 00:00:00 UTC +00:00'
0020-01-26 00:00:00 UTC
main> tt == tt.in_time_zone("UTC")
true
```

OR... if your test is really concerned with what's going to be displayed, then perhaps you should be comparing stringified versions:

```
expect(order.purchased_at.to_s).to eq "0020-01-26 00:00:00 UTC"
```